# Please help with my JSP Internationalization problem

Tags: java, forms, jsp, internationalization

I have problem with I18N in JSP, specifically, with forms.

When I enter some Czech characters (e.g., "ěščřžýá...") into my page one form, into the field "`fieldOne`", and then show text from that field on page two, instead of Czech characters I see this as "ÄÄ".  (Note, the second page gets the Czech characters with "`request.getProperty("fieldOne")`")

Here is the source code:

**Page one:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>

<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
    <form action="druha.jsp" method="post">
       <input type="textarea" name="fieldOne">
       <input type="submit">
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Page two:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>

<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
    <h1>The text: </h1> <%=request.getProperty("fieldOne")%>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which container are you using? This information is important for this kind of problems.

Anyway, try calling

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

before reading the parameter. Sometimes setting the page encoding in the header directive isn't enough. You definitely need to do this in Tomcat and servlets, I assume that this could be also the case for JSPs.

Comment: Aheum... it's setCharacterEncoding actually